# .htaccess redirect 2 http pages to https pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some troubles with redirecting 2 simple html pages.

I need to setup redirect for:

1. http: //example.com/Folder1/page1.html to https://example.com/Folder1/page1.html
2. http: //example.com/Folder1/Folder2/page2.html https://example.com/Folder1/Folder2/page2.html

Only these two pages must be redirected from http to https. Any others pages must be available for both http and https.

I tried with these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 
rewriterule ^(Folder1)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 1=443 
RewriteCond $1 ^Folder1/Folder2 
rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But only second redirect works. The first still opens http page.

Could anyone help me with writing correct rules please?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/Folder1/(page1\.html|Folder2/page2\.html))$ [NC]
rewriterule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is this rules must be placed in .htaccess in a site`s root directory?
or in folder1 .htaccess?

Comment: I try adding this rules into root directory .htaccess file, and works only Folder2.
Maybe the problem that Folder2 is subfolder of Folder1?

Comment: it is better to place them in the .htaccess in site's root directory,
the redirection works fine (I have tested it on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ ) , are you trying to redirect all html pages under Folder2 to https ?